Datos Spinner intents
no se como pasar los datos seleccionados en el spinner a la siguiente Activity, para utilizar los seleccionados. es una aplicación para cuadrar equipos para partidos, con campos y horarios. Adjunto los códigos.
Gracias.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
